# Upload files from web to Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I want to make a form on a website using Google API where user fill in "name", "email" and the file to upload. I want the file to upload in my Google Drive, which is working (followed YT tutorial), but I need to create a new folder named as "name" + "email" from the form or named as "name" and create a file in this folder with content of "email"

I tried this but I've never done anything in .gs so I have no idea how to pass the name from `.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>Upload Files</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Nezávazná poptávka!</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="box" name="name" placeholder="Celé jméno*">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="box" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail*">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="file" name="myFile" mulitple>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="button" id="submitBtn" value="Nahrát soubor">
        <label id="resp"></label>
    </form>
    
    <script>
      document.getElementById('submitBtn').addEventListener('click',
        function(e){
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).uploadFiles(this.parentNode)
        })
        
        function onSuccess(data){
          document.getElementById('resp').innerHTML = "File Uploaded to the path " +data;
        }
       
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}

function uploadFiles(data)
{
 var file = data.myFile;
 var name = data.name;
 var mail = data.mail;
 var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1lnLlX-zB8n4JZyEDdq242hiw2jX4qZWH');
 DriveApp.createFolder(name);
 DriveApp.createFile(mail, mail);
 
 var createFile = folder.createFile(file);
 return createFile.getUrl();
}
```

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+file+upload

Comment: You could exclude Google form questions from the above search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+file+upload+-%5Bgoogle-form%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your `index.html` page the same and complete the task with a few minor edits to you `code.gs`:

```js
function uploadFiles(data){

  var file = data.myFile;
  var name = data.name;
  var mail = data.mail;  

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('<your-folder-id>');
  folder.createFolder(name + " + " + mail);

  var createFile = folder.createFile(file);
  return createFile.getUrl();
}
```

Alternatively, if you want the file to be uploaded to the newly created folder, you can do this by replacing the last three lines:

```js
  folder.createFolder(name + " + " + mail);

  var createFile = folder.createFile(file);
  return createFile.getUrl();
```

with:

```js
  var folderID = folder.createFolder(name + " + " + mail).getId();

  var createFile = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).createFile(file);
  return createFile.getUrl();
```

Comment: @MultiSteelking No worries, Glad to be of help! If the answer is suitable then please accept the answer on the left to help enrich the community and allow users in the future to find solutions which will help them when encountering similar problems.